# Accessing Umbraco Services with Hangfire, getting a SqlTransaction exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, hangfire-sql, umbraco-10

We are using Hangfire with Umbraco v10 to create a recurring job that unpublishes some nodes.

We are getting the following error when the job is triggered:

> System.InvalidOperationException (WN1SDWK000GBL:7100)
> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

```
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()  
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.get_IsolationLevel()  
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Scoping.Scope.get_Database()  
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.ContentTypeCommonRepository.GetAllTypesInternal()  
at Umbraco.Extensions.AppCacheExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<GetCacheItem>b__0()  
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache.SafeLazy.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetSafeLazy>b__0()  
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---  
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache.ObjectCacheAppCache.Get(String key, Func`1 factory, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, String[] dependentFiles)  
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache.DeepCloneAppCache.Get(String key, Func`1 factory, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, String[] dependentFiles)  
at Umbraco.Extensions.AppCacheExtensions.GetCacheItem[T](IAppPolicyCache provider, String cacheKey, Func`1 getCacheItem, Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean isSliding, String[] dependentFiles)  
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.ContentTypeCommonRepository.GetAllTypes()  
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.ContentTypeRepository.GetAllWithFullCachePolicy()  
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.ContentTypeRepositoryBase`1.PerformGetAll(Int32[] ids)  
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache.FullDataSetRepositoryCachePolicy`2.GetAllCached(Func`2 performGetAll)  
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache.FullDataSetRepositoryCachePolicy`2.GetAll(TId[] ids, Func`2 performGetAll)  
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.ContentTypeRepository.PerformGet(String alias)  
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentTypeServiceBase`2.Get(String alias)  
at Skoleforeningenv10.Core.Features.OpenPositions.OpenPositionsService.UnpublishOpenPositions() in C:\home\site\repository\src\Skoleforeningenv10.Core\Features\OpenPositions\OpenPositionsService.cs:line 23
```

This is the code for the service:

```cs
public class OpenPositionsService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public OpenPositionsService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) 
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;    
    }

    public void UnpublishOpenPositions()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var umbracoContextFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUmbracoContextFactory>();
        
        umbracoContextFactory.EnsureUmbracoContext();

        var contentTypeService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContentTypeService>();
        var contentService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContentService>();

        var openPositionType = contentTypeService.Get(OpenPosition.ModelTypeAlias);
        var openPositions = contentService.GetPagedOfType(openPositionType.Id, 0, 1000, out var totalRecords, null, Ordering.By("Id", Direction.Descending))
            .Where(x => x.Published == true);

        foreach (var openPosition in openPositions)
        {
            var endDate = openPosition.GetValue<DateTime?>("endDate");

            if (endDate != null && endDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
                contentService.Unpublish(openPosition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine locally, but not on Umbraco cloud. What might have gone wrong?

Comment: How did you register the IServiceScopeFactory and OpenPositionsService in your dependency container?